# Parse XML nodes to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to get an array of all attributes from element `ROW` from the XML below

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.seavus.com/AML/XML-Schema/CTR_Single.xsd">
  <banka>
    <!-- banka children -->
  </banka>
  <METADATA>
    <FIELDS>
      <!-- Fields -->
    </FIELDS>
    <PARAMS LCID="0" />
  </METADATA>
  <ROWDATA>
    <ROW BANK_ID="370" AKTIVNOST_SE_VRSI_VO_19="Г" NAZIV_21="XXXXX" SEDISTE_21="XX" DANOCEN_BROJ_21="12333" BROJ_SMETKA_21="123333" BANKA_21="330" DATUM_22="03.01.2017" CAS_22="13:30" VID_AKTIV_23="XXX" IZNOS_24="12" VALUTA_24="807" DATUM_25="04.01.2017"
      VREME_25="12:55" SIFRA_26="800" OPIS_27="XXXXXXX" />
  </ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

To be clear, I want to make an array from this node:

```html
<ROW BANK_ID="370" AKTIVNOST_SE_VRSI_VO_19="Г" NAZIV_21="XXXXX" SEDISTE_21="XX" DANOCEN_BROJ_21="12333" BROJ_SMETKA_21="123333" BANKA_21="330" DATUM_22="03.01.2017" CAS_22="13:30" VID_AKTIV_23="XXX" IZNOS_24="12" VALUTA_24="807" DATUM_25="04.01.2017"
  VREME_25="12:55" SIFRA_26="800" OPIS_27="XXXXXXX" />
```

I want to use this array to generate insert query.

What I have tried so far:

```
doc.Load(path);
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
XmlNode idNodes = doc.SelectSingleNode("DATAPACKET/ROWDATA/ROW");
foreach (XmlNode node1 in idNodes.Attributes)
{
    list.Add(node1.InnerText);
}
```

I have classes generated online from my XML and I am using them to deserialize my XML file.

Comment: An array of _what_? Strings, with just those field names? Or do you want an array containing, say, key-value pairs?

Comment: Yes only strings with those field names

Comment: What is DATAROW? I see a DATAPACKET but no DATAROW in your xml

Comment: my mistake fixed the question

Comment: `ROW` has no child nodes. Do  you mean attributes?

Comment: Your main problem is not using the right namespace for your selection. See @Eser's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a dictionary for name-value pairs. Using Linq2Xml :

*(Don't forget the default XmlNamespace)*

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.CreateNavigator().NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.seavus.com/AML/XML-Schema/CTR_Single.xsd");

var dict = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//ns:ROWDATA/ns:ROW",mgr)
                .Attributes()
                .ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a.Value);
```

returned dictionary will be:

```
BANK_ID: 370
AKTIVNOST_SE_VRSI_VO_19: Г
NAZIV_21: XXXXX
SEDISTE_21: XX
DANOCEN_BROJ_21: 12333
BROJ_SMETKA_21: 123333
BANKA_21: 330
DATUM_22: 03.01.2017
CAS_22: 13:30
VID_AKTIV_23: XXX
IZNOS_24: 12
VALUTA_24: 807
DATUM_25: 04.01.2017
VREME_25: 12:55
SIFRA_26: 800
OPIS_27: XXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that you selected from the wrong namespace. Also, of course, there is no DATAROW to select.

This seems to work:

```
doc.Load(yourPath);
var list = new ArrayList();
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.CreateNavigator().NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.seavus.com/AML/XML-Schema/CTR_Single.xsd");
var idNodes = doc.DocumentElement?.SelectSingleNode("ns:ROWDATA/ns:ROW", mgr);
foreach (XmlNode attr in idNodes.Attributes)
    list.Add(attr.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to add key and value to this arraylist?

Comment: `mgr` `ns` `doc.CreateNavigator().NameTable` How similar to mine